# How to implement Javascript ECMA 5's array.map() for sparse array?

Tags: javascript

It should be quite easy to implement `array.map()` that is [defined in ECMA-262](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.4.19), which takes a function and this function will be called by 3 arguments: element value, index, the array.

But what about for sparse array?  Obviously we don't want to iterate from index 0 to 100,000 if only index 0, 1, 2, and 100,000 has an element and otherwise is sparse from index 3 to 99,999. I can think of using `arr.slice(0)` or `arr.concat()` to clone the array, and then put in the replaced values, but what if we don't use `slice` or `concat`, is there another way to do it?

The solution I came up with using `slice()` is:

```
Array.prototype.collect = Array.prototype.collect || function(fn) {
    var result = this.slice(0);

    for (var i in this) {
      if (this.hasOwnProperty(i))
        result[i] = fn(this[i], i, this);  // 3 arguments according to ECMA specs
    }
    return result;
};
```

(`collect` is used to try out the code, as that's another name for `map` in some language)

Comment: `var result = [];` should suffice... why do you want to clone the array? Also note that in some browsers, `length` might be enumerable.

Comment: is that right, would they be the same, that if we set `result = []` and then `result[0] = 1` and then `result[10000] = 2`, then it is a sparse array just like the original array is?

Comment: All indexes that are not set will default to `undefined`, just like any other non-existing properties. How do you define "sparse array" and how do you create one in your case? If you do, `var a = []; a[5] = 42;`, then the length of the array is of course `6`, but it really has only one element at index `5`. You will see that if you do `console.dir(a)`.

Comment: so it seems that if we set some elements in an empty array and they are not consecutive, the array is a sparse array.  I dumped `arr.map` and `arr.collect` results using `console.log` and `console.dir` and they look the same, so looks like you have the answer.  The sparse array I tried was `arr = [1,3,,,,,7,9,11];`

Comment: So does this mean that `array.map` actually works for your purposes?

Comment: ah, it won't work for `arr = [1,3,,,,,7,9,11,,,];`.... because the ending "sparseness" won't go in if using `result = []`  (result printed out using `console.log`)

Comment: Right... but `array.map` seems to work perfectly, at least according to my tests. There is no need to build your own function (or I did not understand the problem).

Comment: right... i am just building it, say, what if it is to run on IE 8 (or IE 7)?

Comment: Have a look at this `.map` polyfill: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map. You could use that one. It also shows that instead of using `var result = [];`, you could use `var result = new Array(this.length);`, if you want to stick with your solution. It might be a bit faster if you really have extremely sparse arrays (and hight indexes).

Comment: so using `var result = new Array(this.length);` will just create an empty, sparse array, and therefore should be quite faster than making a clone of the original, you mean?  Do you want to add this as an answer?

Comment: Well, it's likely to be faster, but that's not what I meant. I meant you could simply use the `array.map` implementation in browsers where it does not exist. But looking at the implementation, it is iterating over each number from `0` to `array.length`, which is probably slower than your solution if you have a very sparse array with large indexes. I can put all these thoughts as an answer if you want to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be easy, but there are a few peculiar points.

The callback function is allowed to modify the array in question.  Any elements it adds or removes are not visited.  So it seems we should use something like Object.keys to determine which elements to visit.

Also, the result is defined to be a new array "created as if by" the array constructor taking the length of the old array, so we might as well use that constructor to create it.

Here's an implementation taking these things into account, but probably missing some other subtleties:

```
function map(callbackfn, thisArg) {
  var keys = Object.keys(this),
    result = new Array(this.length);

  keys.forEach(function(key) {
    if (key >= 0 && this.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      result[key] = callbackfn.call(thisArg, this[key], key, this);
    }
  }, this);

  return result;
}
```

I am assuming Object.keys returns the keys of the array in numerical order, which I think is implementation defined.  If it doesn't, you could sort them.

Comment: how come you define `map` as a simple function and use `this`?  A simple function will have the `this` to mean the global scope...

Comment: You can assign it to a property of an object or prototype after the fact.  For example, `Array.prototype.map = map;` or `var a = []; a.map = map;`  Then when you call it on `a` 'this' will have the proper value.  I could have written `Array.prototype.map = function map...`, I just didn't.

Comment: aha, yeah I wonder how come you create one extra function instead of just assigning to Array.prototype as it is clearly dealing with arrays.  `Array.prototype.map = map` can be done but why create an extra dangling `map`?

Comment: @動靜能量, I don't have some fancy reason for creating a global function instead of just assigning to the array prototype.  However it is interesting to note that ECMA states "The map function is intentionally generic; it does not require that its `this` value be an Array object."

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use `this.slice(0)`. You can just make `result` an array and assign values to any index:

```
Array.prototype.collect = Array.prototype.collect || function(fn) { 
  var result = [];
  for(var i in this) {
    if (this.hasOwnProperty(i)) { 
      result[i] = fn(this[i]);
    }
  }
  return result;
}
```

Comment: this won't work if the sparse array is `[1,2,,,,3,,,]` due to the trailing sparseness, if that is to be the same as the original array

Comment: I think the length property of the result array is supposed to be the same as that of the object being mapped over (more or less).